# Intercept TCP request like burp suite

Tags: networking, proxy

I wanted to know if there were proxy tools like mitmproxy or burp suite to create a proxy and intercept the tcp requests of a program?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the original MITM software would be [Ettercap](https://www.ettercap-project.org/), also included in [Kali](https://www.kali.org/). It has various plugins, but if you want to manipulate data, you would need to add your own module.

If you are comfortable with writing python code, you can also give [tcprpoxy](https://github.com/ickerwx/tcpproxy) a try.

All the simple GUI based MITM inspection tools are targeted at HTTP, which is all text based and makes editing generally possible. TCP connections can be purely binary, which makes creating a generic easy-to-use editor much harder.

So you will usually  need to supply some kind of function to be called upon packet capture, which then can bit manipulate the packet.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help, I'll look into it.